# How to show results in a list Grails gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the Student class that has a relationship one-to-many with the Note class

```
class Student {
   String name
   static hasMany = [notes: Note]
}

class Note {
    double note
    int bimester
    static belongsTo = [student:Student]
}
```

When I display the result to the user in my userNotes.gsp
It is shown:
I use: `<g:each var="n" in="${studentInstance.notes}">`

```
Discipline    Note  Bimester
mathematics | 0    |   1
mathematics | 0    |   2
mathematics | 0    |   3
mathematics | 0    |   4
portuguese  | 0    |   1
portuguese  | 0    |   2
portuguese  | 0    |   3
portuguese  | 0    |   4
```

But I wanted to show the following:

```
Discipline | Bimester 1 | Bimester 2 | Bimester 3 | Bimester 4
mathematics      0            0            0            0
portuguese       0            0            0            0
```

Comment: I suggest that you look into the findAll tag as it is explained here and figure out the best solution for your specific problem:

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/findAll.html

My best bet would be to combine it with the if tag:http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/if.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the data in the controller:

```
def userNotes() {
   def student = Student.get(1)
   def disciplines = [:].withDefault { [0, 0, 0, 0] }
   for (Note note in student.notes.sort { it.bimester }) {
       disciplines[note.discipline].set(note.bimester - 1, note.note)
   }
   [disciplines: disciplines]
}
```

and display it with

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Discipline</th>
            <th>Bimester 1</th>
            <th>Bimester 2</th>
            <th>Bimester 3</th>
            <th>Bimester 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each in="${disciplines}" var="entry">
        <tr>
            <td>${entry.key}</td>
            <g:each in="${entry.value}" var='bimester'>
            <td>${bimester}</td>
            </g:each>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
```